# I want to restrict HTML input autocomplete to 3 letter minimum

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a website it has a Autocomplet in search but unfortunately its allowing a single letter to Auto-complete. But I want it to minimum 3 letter to show the drop-down Auto-complete.

I tried with this and the Autocomplete not working

```
if(event.which != 13 && val > 3){
```

Below is the Jquery which is doing the Autocomplete.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.st-location-name').each(function(index, el) {
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        var parent = $(this).parents('.st-select-wrapper');
        var t = $(this);
        var flag = true;
        t.keyup(function(event) {
            val = $(this).val();
            if(event.which != 13 && val != ""){
                flag = false;

                html = '';
                $('select option', parent).prop('selected', false);

                $('select option', parent).each(function(index, el) {
                    var country = $(this).data('country');
                    var text = $(this).text();
                    var text_split = text.split("||");
                    text_split = text_split[0];
                    var highlight = get_highlight(text, val);
                    if(highlight.indexOf('</span>') >= 0){
                        var current_country = $(this).parent('select').attr('data-current-country');
                        if(typeof current_country != 'undefined' && current_country != ''){
                            if(country == current_country){
                                html += '<div data-text="'+text+'" data-country="'+country+'" data-value="'+$(this).val()+'" class="option">'+
                                    '<span class="label">'+text_split+'<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>'+
                                    '</div>';
                            }
                        }else{
                            html += '<div data-text="'+text+'" data-country="'+country+'" data-value="'+$(this).val()+'" class="option">'+
                                '<span class="label">'+text_split+'<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>'+
                                '</div>';   
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('.option-wrapper',parent).html(html).show();  
            }else{
                $('.option-wrapper',parent).html('').hide();
            }
            if(typeof t.data('children') != 'undefined' && t.data('children') != ""){
                name = t.data('children');
                $('select[name="'+name+'"]', form).attr('data-current-country','');
                $('input[name="drop-off"]', form).val('');
                $('select[name="'+name+'"] option', form).prop('selected', false);
            }

        });
        t.keydown(function(event) {
            /* Act on the event */
            if(event.which == 13){
                return false;
            }
        });
        t.blur(function(event) {
            if(t.data('clear') == 'clear' && $('select option:selected',parent).val() == ""){
                t.val('');
            }
        });
        t.focus(function(event) {
            if(typeof t.data('parent') != 'undefined' && t.data('parent') != ""){
                name = t.data('parent');
                if($('select[name="'+name+'"]', form).length){
                    var val = $('select[name="'+name+'"]', form).parent().find('input.st-location-name').val();
                    if(typeof val == 'undefined' || val == ''){
                        t.val('');
                        $('select[name="'+name+'"]', form).parent().find('input.st-location-name').focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        parent.on('click', '.option-wrapper .option', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            /* Act on the event */
            flag = true;

            var value = $(this).data('value');
            var text = $(this).text();
            var country = $(this).data('country');
            t.val(text);
            $('select option[value="'+value+'"]', parent).prop('selected', true);

            $('.option-wrapper',parent).html('').hide();

            if(typeof t.data('children') != 'undefined' && t.data('children')!= ""){
                name = t.data('children');
                $('select[name="'+name+'"]', form).attr('data-current-country', country);
            }
        });
        $(document).click(function(event) {
            if(!$(event.target).is('.st-location-name')){
                $('.option-wrapper').html('').hide();
            }
        });
        form.submit(function(event) {

            if(t.val() == "" && t.hasClass('required')){
                t.focus();
                return false;
            }else{
                if($('input.required-field').length && $('input.required-field').prop('checked') == true){
                    var val = $('select[name="location_id_pick_up"] option:selected', form).val();
                    var text = $('input[name="pick-up"]', form).val();
                    $('select[name="location_id_drop_off"] option[value="'+val+'"]', form).prop('selected', true);
                    $('input[name="drop-off"]', form).val(text);
                }
                if($('input.required-field').length && $('input.required-field').prop('checked') == false && $('input[name="drop-off"]', form).val() == ""){
                    $('input[name="drop-off"]', form).focus();
                    $('select[name="location_id_drop_off"] option', form).prop('selected', false);
                    return false;
                }
            }   
        });
    });

    function get_highlight(text, val) {
        var highlight = text.replace(
            new RegExp(val + '(?!([^<]+)?>)', 'gi'),
            '<span class="highlight">$&</span>'
        );
        return highlight;
    }

});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input.required-field').each(function(index, el) {
        var form = $(this).parents('form');

        if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
            $('.form-drop-off', form).addClass('field-hidden');
        }else{
            $('.form-drop-off', form).removeClass('field-hidden');
        }
        $(this).on('ifToggled', function(event){
            $('.form-drop-off', form).toggleClass('field-hidden');
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
if(event.which != 13 && val.length > 3){
```

I beleive the issue with your version is your saying if val > 3 so if the text in the field was "test" then you're saying:

```
if("test" > 3)
```

whereas you want to know if the length of the value is greater than 3. Hence

```
val.length
```

Comment: You're welcome, if it works then please accept the answer too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `length` of the `val`, not the `val` itself:

```
if (event.which != 13 && val.length > 3) {
```